# Updating An Array With Query

Tags: algorithm, tree

There are `N` students initially they all have 0 score. Now we are giving `Q` query in each query we increase the marks of `A index students by B`. Now rearrange the student i increasing rank i.e. The Highest score will be one , second Highest second and so on...
For each student, his or her place is equal to the number of student with more marks, increased by 1.

Let's define `hash of participant` as the product of his/her place and the number of points. After each query,  find the `sum` of hashes of participants

For Example:

```
N=4 Q=4
3 100
2 60
1 80
2 20
1 20

After the first query, participant 3 has 100 and is 1, with hash equal to 
100. The sum of hashes is 100+0+0+0=100


After the second query, participant 2 has the second place with 60 and hash 
120, in total 100+120+0+0 = 220


After the third query, the Rank looks like follows: 
(100,80,60,0). The sum of hashes is 200+160+180+0= 440

In the fourth query participant  the rank is (100,80,80,0) then, with the sum 
100⋅1+80⋅2+80⋅2+0⋅4=420.
```

How can we do it efficiently one simple approch is here find index and replace it:

```
while(Q>0){
    Q--;
    int a = in.nextInt()-1;
    long b = in.nextInt();
    if(score.size()==0){
        score.add(b);
        A[a]=b;
        System.out.println(b);
    }else{
        int index =-1;
        if(A[a]!=0){


            int s =0;
            int e = score.size()-1;
            while(s<=e){

                int mid = (s+e)/2;
                if(score.get(mid)==A[a]){
                    index = mid;
                    break;
                }else if(score.get(mid)>A[a]) s = mid+1;
                else e = mid-1;
            }
        }
        A[a]+=b;
        int replace= score.size();
        int s =0;
        int e = score.size()-1;
        while(s<=e){

            int mid = (s+e)/2;
            if(score.get(mid)>A[a]) s = mid+1;
            else{
                replace = mid;
                e = mid-1;
            }
        }

        score.add(replace,A[a]);
        if(index!=-1) score.remove(index+1);


        long o= score.get(0);
        long prev =1;
        for(int i=1;i<score.size();i++){

             if(score.get(i)!=score.get(i-1)){

                  prev =i+1;
                  o+=score.get(i)*prev;
             }else o+=score.get(i)*(prev);

        }
        System.out.println(o);



    }
}
```

How Can we do it more efficiently by using segment tree or any other data structure.

Answer (score 0):

The slow part of your solution is that you recompute the hash after every query (O(N*Q)).

To make it faster you need to reuse the previous result as much as possible.
So let's look at what happens to the hash sum after a query.

Let's say you pick the student at position `x` and move him in the ordered list to position `y` (by increasing the score). For the hash sum:

- the partial sum up to y-1 stays the same (there was no change there).
- the partial sum after x+1 stays the same (there was no change there).
- you need to decrease x*old_score and add y*new_score to account for the student move.
- For the students between y and x-1, they become y +1...x. So for the hash sum needs to increase by the sum of their scores.

All these operations can be done in at most O(logN) to lower the overall complexity to O(QlogN) (much better).

So you need a data structure that allows you to insert, remove and compute partial sums in O(logN) or better. I would suggest a balanced binary tree(or a skip list). Each node should keep track of how many nodes are below and what the sum of their scores are. To find the x'th element you can use the number of nodes and to find the sum you can use the partial sums.

With this tree you don't need to change the indices of the nodes (they change automatically when you insert something in front of them). If you want to do it with a segment tree you will need a lot of care because of moving nodes.

Example:

Say the current state of scores looks like `[100, 90, 80, 70, 60, 50, 40, 30]`. The next query is `5 35` so we have find the fifth element (the one with score 60, you find it using the number of elements below a node to guide your search) and increase it by 35. After the increase the score will be  95 so it goes into the second position (you find this by looking for the value in the binary search tree). So x is 5, y is 2. The hashsum update is `hashsum += 95 * 2 - 60 * 5 + (90+80+70)`. The last sum you can find in the binary tree using the partial sums mentioned.

Comment: @user6250837 I've added an example, hope it makes it clearer.